# Strange upper limit of CPU usage

Tags: windows-8, intel-core-i7, visual-studio-2012

**Some background info:**

I'm a .NET developer working on a Dell Precision M4500 notebook (i7 X 940 @ 2,1 | 8GB DDR3 | [Details](http://speccy.piriform.com/results/zhOIt1NAkmXaszTeYiBeFIU)). Tools I use on daily basis (and which are basically open the whole work day): two instances of Visual Studio 2012 (+ Windows Azure Emulator), Chrome with several Tabs, TortoiseHg (version control tool), Outlook, Skype -> Normal setup nothing special I think.

Stats during normal use:

Avg. CPU load: 15-20%. Avg. Memory: 2-3GB (30-40%)

**Problem:**

Several weeks ago we (two coworker and me, all with the same notebook model) moved from Win7 to Win8 (fresh install -> no upgrade), since then I'm encountering some performance issues. From time to time (mostly, but not always after building and running our application) my notebook is barely usable for several minutes -> UI extremly slow or doesn't respond at all. Even after I stop the debugging session, notebook is extrem slow. After a few minutes, CPU load goes done and I can continue working.

Stats during performance peak use:

CPU load: 56%. Memory: 5-6GB (60-70%)
Also high read/write activities on `C:\pagefile.sys` according to ResourceMonitor (I guess that's normal?).

First strange thing: the max. CPU Utilisation **never** exceeds 56% (none of the CPU goes over 56% see picture below).

[image: CPU Utilisation]

Second strange thing: only my notebook is experiencing those performance issues.

**Things I've tried:**

I've already installed latest driver for graphic card (NVIDIA) and intel chipset. Also compared my notebook with the coworker notebooks -> same software, same driver, same project setup, no greater differences. Installed and run the Intel Processor Diagnostic Tool -> Passed. Also no defect or error on the RAM.

And yes, I also checked the power settings (I'm using High performance), the maximum processor state is set to 100%.

**The Question:**

I know nobody can tell me the exact cause of this specific problem.

But my question is, why is the CPU load **never** exceeding 56%? Where does this strange limitation come from?

Maybe solving this mystery will bring me a step closer to the solution of the performance problem.

Comment: I had almost the same problem when I decided to try to work on Win8, after few hours I decided it`s easier to go back and again use Win7 without any problems.

Comment: Check this link: http://forums.guru3d.com/showthread.php?t=370420
Maybe you can find an answer.

Comment: @Nidzaaaa and Griffin: Unfortunately I can't go back to Win7, we are using WebSockets (.NET 4.5) which are not natively supported under Win7 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039438/using-websocket-on-windows7).

Comment: Other than the weird CPU load, sounds to me like Windows 8 is thrashing for some reason

Comment: Have you tried forcing it to go over the 56% limit by using a benchmarking or "burn-in" program (like Prime95)?

Comment: I've tried Prime95. CPU load goes up to 100% and after several seconds goes down to 56% (http://i47.tinypic.com/262ob9u.png)

Comment: But have you tried to open Task Manger (or Resource Monitor) and sort processes by CPU utilization to see which processes are actually responsible to slowing down your computer?

Comment: @DesmondHume Yes of course, mostly the Visual Studio processes or MSBuild or vshost32.exe but none of them is exceeding more than 15-20% CPU utilization. But there is no process which has a huge CPU load (e.g. >30%).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After additional research (BIOS diagnostic test), I discovered that the temperature of my CPU was at 80°C (GPU @ 75~80°C).

So I thought maybe some cleaning would do the trick. I openend the Notebook (as described in the documentation of the notebook I found online @ dell.com), disassembled the heat pipe and the CPU cooler fan and carefully cleaned them, put the things together and started the laptop. After five workdays my notebook works just fine, I think the overheating was the root of the problem. CPU and GPU are now @ 60-65°C.